# How does the RMS package's nomogram calculate points for continuous variables?

Tags: r, logistic, risk

I have been reading a number of papers where researchers have created risk scores based on logistic regression models. Often they refer to "[Sullivan's method](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15122742)" but I have no access to this paper and the explanations provided are far from clear. I noticed that Dr. Harrell's excellent RMS package provides a nomogram function which is in a way similar to creating a risk score (albeit with a very pretty graphical output).

It seems after tinkering around with it that the way it works is by dividing the beta coefficients by the smallest beta coefficient and then multiplying a constant to create points for categorical variables. However I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on with continuous variables. I've spent hours searching google without much luck, and I would appreciate if someone could shed some light on this for me. Thanks!

Comment: The code tells all, but is not easy to read.  Basically one figures out how to scale linear predictors, and evaluates the linear predictor $X\beta$ at a grid of predictor settings.  This takes into account complexities automatically (nonlinear terms, interaction terms).